# 'return' outside function error - python

Tags: python

In line 7, I get the error 'return' outside function and I have tried indention and that's not the issue so I'm not sure what is?

```
 import psycopg2
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    app = Flask(__name__)
    def getConn():
        connStr=("dbname='----' user='----' password= '----' " )
    conn=psycopg2.connect(connStr)
    return conn
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template('part3.html')
    @app.route('/displayStudent', methods =['GET'])
    def displayCustomer():
        @app.route('/addStudent', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
        def addLeadCustomer():
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Check your indent. `return conn` has indentation but it is outside any function.

Comment: click before the return on line 7 and then hit the tab key or space 4 times

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
import psycopg2
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
def getConn():
    connStr=("dbname='----' user='----' password= '----' " )
    conn=psycopg2.connect(connStr)
    return conn

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('part3.html')

@app.route('/displayStudent', methods =['GET'])
def displayCustomer():
    pass

@app.route('/addStudent', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def addLeadCustomer():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug = True)
```

I Hope this will work. Thanks.